# bash script append text to first line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, raspbian

I want to add a text to the end of the first line of a file using a bash script.
The file is /etc/cmdline.txt which does not allow line breaks and needs new commands seperated by a blank, so text i want to add realy needs to be in first line.

What i got so far is:

```
line=' bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=20'
file=/boot/cmdline.txt
if ! grep -q -x -F -e "$line" <"$file"; then
  printf '%s' "$line\n" >>"$file"
fi
```

But that appends the text after the line break of the first line, so the result is wrong.
I either need to trim the file contend, add my text and a line feed or somehow just add it to first line of file not touching the rest somehow, but my knowledge of bash scripts is not good enough to find a solution here, and all the examples i find online add beginning/end of every line in a file, not just the first line.

Comment: `grep "$line" "$file"` use this instead @RyuKajiya I have just tried it working fine on my terminal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This `sed` command will add `123` to end of first line of your file.

```
sed ' 1 s/.*/&123/' yourfile.txt
```

also

```
sed '1 s/$/ 123/' yourfile.txt
```

For appending result to the same file you have to use `-i` switch :

```
sed -i ' 1 s/.*/&123/' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: What about `sed '1 s/$/ 123/'` ? =)

Comment: Yeah that also will work thanks @sputnick I'm adding this too.

Comment: sed ' 1 s/.*/&bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=20/' "$file" > "$file" just cleared the whole file...

Comment: Check again @RyuKajiya, updated the command as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, first writing to a temp file, then moving to the wanted file works!
Now i just have a problem that the check if the file allready contains the text doesnt work. It allways adds the text, even if it is allready there

Comment: check the added string using `grep` before running this command if found then ignore execution @RyuKajiya

Comment: thats what i am doing allready, check code above. But seems the check fails somehow

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution to add "ok" at the first line on `/etc/passwd`, I think you can use this in your script with a little bit of 'tuning' :

```
$ awk 'NR==1{printf "%s %s\n", $0, "ok"}' /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash ok
```

Comment: So i would do printf awk 'NR==1{printf "%s %s\n", $0, "bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=20"}' /boot/cmdline.txt >> "$file" ?

Comment: Do you really need `sudo` here ? I suspect **no!** For the rest, seems fine !

Comment: Doesn't work, i edited the printf line to the one in above comment, but the file does not get modified

Comment: `awk` don't modify the file _in-place_, you need to use a temporary file or use `sed -i ...`

Comment: This updates the first line, but gets rid of every other line.

Answer (score 2):

To *edit* a file, you can use `ed`, the standard editor:

```
line=' bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=20'
file=/boot/cmdline.txt
if ! grep -q -x -F -e "$line" <"$file"; then
    ed -s "$file" < <(printf '%s\n' 1 a "$line" . 1,2j w q)
fi
```

`ed`'s commands:

- `1`: go to line 1
- `a`: append (this will insert after the current line)
- We're in insert mode and we're inserting the expansion of `$line`
- `.`: stop insert mode
- `1,2j` join lines 1 and 2
- `w`: write
- `q`: quit

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to append a variable to the first line of input:

```
awk -v suffix="$suffix" '{print NR==1 ? $0 suffix : $0}'
```

This will work even if the variable could potentially contain regex formatting characters.

Example:

```
suffix=' [first line]'
cat input.txt | awk -v suffix="$suffix" '{print NR==1 ? $0 suffix : $0}' > output.txt
```

input.txt:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

output.txt:

```
Line 1 [first line]
Line 2
Line 3
```